# Number of windows on screen (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv

is there a method to know the number of windows created using *namedWindow* or should I use a global variable or something like that?

Comment: there is no such thing. also, since imshow() might open windows, too (without calling namedWindow() explicitly), your global variable might be off.

Comment: you could try to find ALL open windows (e.g. with winAPI for windows). Maybe those OpenCV windows have some common properties or you can decide from name?!? Another possibility might be to look a the `cv::imshow` or `cv::namedWindow` code, I guess there is some global openCV structure that checks whether a window with that name already exists. If you change that openCV code, you might be able to add functionality to access a list with all those windows. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @berak and @Micka commented, there is currently no way to do that.

If you want to write your own *platform-specific* implementation to do this, I suggest you look at the implementation of [`cvDestroyAllWindows()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?destroyallwindows#destroyallwindows) . This is a [*per-platform* implementation](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cvDestroyAllWindows&type=Code), but it does iterate through all windows opened with *namedWindow* or *imshow*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
cv2.imread("nums/lon.png")
pictures = []
pictures.append(["picture 1 ", cv2.imread("nums/lon.png")])
pictures.append(["picture 2 ", cv2.imread("nums/lon.png")])
pictures.append(["picture 3 ", cv2.imread("nums/lon.png")])
for picture in pictures:
    name, pic = picture
    cv2.imshow(name, pic)
while True and len(pictures) > 0:
    key = cv2.waitKey(150)
    for c, picture in enumerate(pictures):
        name, pic = picture
        if (key == 27) or cv2.getWindowProperty(name,cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
            pictures = pictures[0:c]+pictures[c+1:]
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```